# Deseo obtener los datos de mis usuarios de firebase, estoy utilizando realtime

Tags: java, firebase

Este es mi código

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/Users/jazmin/NetBeansProjects/Gama/src/main/resources/datagama.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://datagama-f53c8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    System.out.println("FirebaseApp inicializado correctamente.");

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    System.out.println("Instancia de FirebaseDatabase obtenida correctamente.");

    DatabaseReference usuariosRef = database.getReference("usuarios");

    System.out.println("Referencia a 'usuarios' obtenida correctamente.");



    // Añadir ChildEventListener a la referencia de 'usuarios'
    usuariosRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            // Este método se llama cuando se añade un nuevo hijo a 'usuarios'
            String userId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            String nombre = dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
            String noPromotor = dataSnapshot.child("noPromotor").getValue(String.class);
            String password = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);

            // Imprimir los datos del usuario
            System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
            System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombre);
            System.out.println("No. Promotor: " + noPromotor);
            System.out.println("Contraseña: " + password);
            System.out.println("--------------------");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            // Este método se llama cuando un hijo existente en 'usuarios' se modifica
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Este método se llama cuando un hijo existente en 'usuarios' es eliminado
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            // Este método se llama cuando un hijo existente en 'usuarios' cambia de posición
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Este método se llama cuando hay un error en la operación
        }
    });
}
}
```

y esto es lo que me imprime FirebaseApp inicializado correctamente.

```
Instancia de FirebaseDatabase obtenida correctamente.
20:40:50.698 [main] DEBUG com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp - Starting the proactive token refresher
20:40:50.699 [main] DEBUG com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp - Scheduling next token refresh in 0 milliseconds
20:40:50.700 [firebase-scheduled-worker] DEBUG com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp - Refreshing OAuth2 credential
Referencia a 'usuarios' obtenida correctamente.
20:40:50.705 [firebase-database-worker] DEBUG com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnection - [pc_0] Scheduling connection attempt
20:40:50.705 [firebase-database-worker] DEBUG com.google.firebase.database.connection.util.RetryHelper - Scheduling retry in 0ms
---------------------------------------------------------
```

esta es mi base de datos

```
"usuarios": {
    "123": {
      "noPromotor": 123,
      "nombre": "jazmin",
      "password": "123",
      "supervisor": "jazmin"
    },
    "Alee23": {
      "noPromotor": "Alee23",
      "nombre": "jaz",
      "password": "123",
      "supervisor": "Jazmin2001"
    },
    "Angel": {
      "noPromotor": 234,
      "nombre": "Angel",
      "password": "angel12"
    },
    "Jazmin2001": {
      "noPromotor": 2001,
      "nombre": "Jazmin Alvarado",
      "password": "jazmin"
    },
    "jaz": {
      "noPromotor": 123,
      "nombre": "jazmin",
      "password": "jazmin"
    }
```

Comment: Cual es el problema? Firebase esta inicializado.

Comment: Buenas, Alejandra, ¿ese es todo el código de tu aplicación java? Si es así me da la sensación de que el problema es que tu método main termina su ejecución justo despues de establecer el listener. Normalmente ese tipo de listeners se registran como parte de una aplicación "mayor" que se está ejecutando todo el rato usando algún framework adicional como Swing, Android o Spring.